# How to reference var from frame on timeline in an object class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, object, movieclip

I'm using Flash Professional cs5/AS3

I'll try and describe this the best I can. I'm new to ActionScript.

So, in my timeline I have a var on a frame that represents "lives" and i have some code in the timeline that takes down the number of lives depending on certain events, which all works great.

so, now i wanted to make a constructor class that I could reuse for a bunch of movie clip objects and I only want these objects to be able to move if the lives variable is greater than certain number. So now, building my constructor class for these objects i just wanted put an if statement that is looking to see if the lives are greater than a certain number, which if it is then should make these objects do what i want...But, when i run the project I get "1120: Access of undefined property lives." lives is the var I made obviously like I said, and it works fine being referenced everyone else except when I make a new .as file for these objects then try and reference it. I get the same error when I try and establish "lives" in the main project class too. I'm not sure where I should put this var or how I can make it so i can reference it from an object class.

I'm not really sure how to word or describe my issue which has made it hard to search for a tutorial. Any suggestions i'm sure this has to be a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are definitely good solutions and were very helpful, the first one may be better. But what i decided to use for my situation was just create a function on the main frame that contained the code to decrease a life. Then I just ran the function from the other fram by doing this

```
//created a var in my movieclip that "contained" the main timeline
var main:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent.parent);

//then simply ran the function from the movieclip
main.decreaseLife();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make "lives" into a static variable in your class file. You should know that there is some controversy on whether or not static vars are a good thing, but if your project is not too big and it works for you then you can use it. It's certainly easy.

If you declare something as static in a class, it will become global (=available to all your code).

Basically you write this in your class (.as) file:

```
public static var lives:uint = 99;
```

Now, in your timeline code you have to replace the var you are using with this one. You access static vars by typing out the class name followed by a dot and the name of the static var. Example: Your class is named "MyClass". Then you access the var by typing MyClass.lives

You do have to import the class file, but I assume you know how that works and with CS5 auto-complete (ctrl+spacebar) I think it does it for you. It'll be something like this:

```
import myclassdirectory.MyClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered best practice to use the timeline for your graphic assets and external classes for code , this will give you far more flexibility and problems such as the one you mention shouldn't prove too difficult to solve.

Consider some parameters in your document class.

```
 public class MyDocumentClass
 {
      //An Object to store various parameters,
      //you could also use separate vars depending on
      //your MCs requirements
      private var params:Object ;

      public function MyDocumentClass
      {
          params = {};
          params.lives = 99;

          //Create a new MovieClip instance
          var myObject:MyObject = new MyObject( params );

          //fron now on you can access the lives property in your object
          addChild( myObject );

      }
  }
```